# Mysql Query : filter with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, filter

I have a table Orders(OID, OrderType, ODep, ReqUser)

i want to filter like below logic:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders if  (Ordertype='confidential') filter by ReqUser='$UserID'  else filter by ODep
```

i am not sure if it is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these situations you can generally replace `if a then b else c` with `(a AND b) OR ((NOT a) AND c)`, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE (Ordertype='confidential' AND ReqUser='$UserID')
   OR (Ordertype<>'confidential' AND ODep)
;
```

Alternatively, depending on your data, this may work as well:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE ReqUser='$UserID'
   OR (Ordertype<>'confidential' AND ODep)
;
```

or this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE ODep AND (ReqUser='$UserID' OR Ordertype <> 'confidential')
;
```

Comment: Nope, what if the requested ReqUser does not exist?

Comment: @dnoeth Then it will filter by whatever `ODep` evaluates to.

Comment: You might want to include an `Ordertype<>'confidential'` clause in your second `OR` condition.

Comment: @Marvin that is good point, and I would guess that is probably the more desired result... correcting.